# Does python support unicode beyond basic multilingual plane?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Below is a simple test. `repr` seems to work fine. yet `len` and `x for x in` doesn't seem to divide the unicode text correctly in Python 2.6 and 2.7:

```
In [1]: u""
Out[1]: u'\U0002f920\U0002f921'

In [2]: [x for x in u""]
Out[2]: [u'\ud87e', u'\udd20', u'\ud87e', u'\udd21']
```

Good news is Python 3.3 does the right thing ™.

Is there any hope for Python 2.x series?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, provided you compiled your Python with wide-unicode support.

By default, Python is built with narrow unicode support only. Enable wide support with:

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

You can verify what configuration was used by testing [`sys.maxunicode`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode):

```
import sys
if sys.maxunicode == 0x10FFFF:
    print 'Python built with UCS4 (wide unicode) support'
else:
    print 'Python built with UCS2 (narrow unicode) support'
```

A wide build will use UCS4 characters for *all* unicode values, doubling memory usage for these. Python 3.3 switched to variable width values; only enough bytes are used to represent all characters in the current value.

Quick demo showing that a wide build handles your sample Unicode string correctly:

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxunicode
1114111
>>> [x for x in u'\U0002f920\U0002f921']
[u'\U0002f920', u'\U0002f921']
```

Comment: Which encoding does 3.3 use?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: See [PEP 393](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393); up to UCS4, dropping down to UCS2 if the 2 LSB bytes are 0 for all characters, down to Latin-1 if the remaining LSB is 0 for all characters.

Comment: osx bundled 2.5, 2.6, 2.7: 0xffff
python.org 2.6.5: 0xffff
python.org 3.3: 0x10ffff
pypy-2.0.2: 0x10ffff

Comment: @qarma: Python 3.3 did away with narrow vs. wide altogether, so `sys.maxunicode` is hardcoded to 0x10ffff there. Any Python 2 versions bundled with OS X releases are all narrow (but modern macOS releases use Python 3).