# Levenshtein distance in Python - wrong result with national characters

Tags: python, diacritics, levenshtein-distance

I found similar topic: [Levenshtein distance on diacritic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271656/levenshtein-distance-on-diacritic-characters), but it's PHP and I write in Python. Still, problem remains the same. For instance: 
levenshtein(kot, kod) = 1
levenshtein(się, sie) = 2, which is wrong. 
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? Do you input or cast strings to unicode (e.g. `u"się"`, or `unicode(raw_input())`)?

Comment: Python 2.7, coding utf-8 and sys.argv.
Well, I just discovered that len(anything-with-national-characters) is longer than normal
len(się) = 4. Just why? :(

Comment: I also tried: 
word1 = unicode(sys.argv[1]) and/or word1 = sys.argv[1] word1 = unicode(word1) and it stopped counting it as word (throws exception that I need two arguments and only gave one)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make sure that the strings are both in unicode. For Python 3 you have that automatically, but in Python 2 you have to decode the strings to `unicode` type first. For example `sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')`, if you know that the encoding in the console is UTF-8. You may try to guess this encoding with [`sys.stdin.encoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012571/python-which-encoding-is-used-for-processing-sys-argv).

After that you may have to normalize unicode. For example unicode strings `u'\u00c7'` and `u'\u0043\u0327'` have the same representation Ç, but they would compare as non-equal, and would have non-zero levenshtein distance. To normalize strings you can use `unicodedata.normalize` function.

The script in Python 2 might look something like this:

```
import unicodedata
import sys
# import or define your levenshtein function here

def decode_and_normalize(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', s.decode('utf-8'))

s1 = decode_and_normalize(sys.argv[1])
s2 = decode_and_normalize(sys.argv[2])
print levenshtein(s1, s2)
```

And after all that you may still run into problems if the characters are outside [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). On this issue look at this [stackoverlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388486/does-python-support-unicode-beyond-basic-multilingual-plane).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! (I can't give upvotes due to small reputation).

Comment: Anyway, now I'm trying to slightly change the Leveshtein distance algorithm in a way that words with national characters and without them are treated as equal. For example: levenshtein(się, sie) = 0, levenshtein(jąkać, jakać) = 0 and so on. I created a list of national substitutions: [['ę', 'e'], ['ą', 'a'] ... ], but getting an error: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal. How to fix this?

Comment: @user4598392 I think you can still accept the answer. To have a unicode literal in Python 2 put `u` before the string. So the substitutions will be `[[u'ę', u'e'], [u'ą', u'a'] ... ]`.

Comment: I want to write thanks (after so long time) ;)
And please, close the topic or sth, because problem is solved.